# Match only first and last character of a string

Tags: java, regex

I had a look at other *stackoverflow* questions and couldn't find one that asked the same question, so here it is:

How do you match the first and last characters of a string (can be multi-line or empty).

So for example:

```
String = "this is a simple sentence"
```

Note that the string includes the beginning and ending quotation marks.

How do I get match the first and last characters where the string begins and ends with a quotation mark (").

I tried:

```
^"|$" and \A"\Z"
```

but these do not produce the desired result.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Did you try this: `".*"` (as regexp), should look like this if you enter it as string `"\".*\""`

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. Match *what* with the first and last characters? You've given an example input, but not explained why your regex should or shouldn't match it.

Comment: @Kaj The `.*` doesn't allow for new-line characters, so that would be an issue for me. @Jon Skeet, I want to get a match of the first and last character when they're both a quotation mark. If that makes sense.

Comment: @Sinker. Yes it does. Just create the pattern with the `DOTALL` flag set, or prepend the pattern string with `(?s)`. See the example that I now have posted. It prints start and end position.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to indicate helpful answers. I'll do that retrospectively as soon as I get more reputation. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String input = "\"this is a simple sentence\"";
String result = input.replaceFirst("(?s)^\"(.*)\"$", " $1 ");
```

This will replace the first and last character of the input string with spaces if it starts and ends with `"`.  It will also work across multiple lines since the `DOTALL` flag is specified by `(?s)`.

Comment: Hi @wjans, this is similar to Kaj's answer, so as I said to Kaj, the only issue I have with this answer is that it matches the whole string and not just the first and last quotation marks (which is what I wanted). Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you want then?  Can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to replace the first character and last character of a string with blank, only when the first and last characters are a quotation mark. Hence `"this is a simple"""" sentence"` becomes `this is a simple"""" sentence`.  Bohemian got the answer down below. Cheers

Comment: That's exactly what this replacement does.  If it starts _and_ ends with `"`, it's replaced by a space.  If that's not the case, the string is not changed.

Comment: When I tried your regex, i got a blank as a return string. The `.*` matches any string.

Comment: Yes, but that part is specified in the replacement by `$1`, which is the content matching against the `.*` (== the part between the start and end `"`).  Unless you specify `""` as input, it can never be empty.

Comment: I didn't use the "$1 " so fair enough.

Comment: Ok, that was crucial to the solution ;)  Also, did you notice that Bohemian's solution replaces when it starts OR ands with `"`?  My solution replaces only in case of AND.  Depends on your requirements...

Comment: In conjunction with string.ReplaceAll, his REGEX does the job. I'll have to give your REGEX a go. I'll also try to make my requirements clearer next time. Cheers

Comment: That's not what I meant.  His regex will also change `"this is a string with only a starting quote` into `this is a string with only a starting quote`, mine will leave the input string untouched in that case.  And _that_'s subject to your requirements.

Comment: I tested you REGEX and found that when i remove the spaces around the $1 replace string, it produces the right result, even when the string is on multiple lines and begins or ends with a quotation mark.

Answer (score 2):

The regex that matches the whole input `".*"`. In java, it looks like this:

```
String regex = "\".*\"";
System.out.println("\"this is a simple sentence\"".matches(regex)); // true
System.out.println("this is a simple sentence".matches(regex));     // false
System.out.println("this is a simple sentence\"".matches(regex));   // false
```

If you want to *remove* the quotes, use this:

```
String input = "\"this is a simple sentence\"";
input = input.replaceAll("(^\"|\"$)", "")); // this is a simple sentence (without any quotes)
```

If you want this to work over multiple lines, use this:

```
String input = "\"this is a simple sentence\"\n\"and another sentence\"";
System.out.println(input + "\n");
input = input.replaceAll("(?m)(^\"|\"$)", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

which produces output:

```
"this is a simple sentence"
"and another sentence"

this is a simple sentence
and another sentence
```

Explanation of regex `(?m)(^"|"$)`:

- `(?m)` means "Caret and dollar match after and before newlines for the remainder of the regular expression"
- `(^"|"$)` means `^"` OR `"$`, which means "start of line then a double quote" OR "double quote then end of line"

Comment: Close...I was hoping to be able to use strings with new-line characters as well.

Comment: Moving target eh? OK, see answer

Comment: `(^\"|\"$)` works like magic. Thanks a lot :) I used `String.replaceAll("(^\"|\"$)", "")` for the String `"A\n\B\"C"` and I got back `A\nB\"C`. Fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the simple logic of getting the first and last characters based on `charAt` method of String? Place a few checks for empty/incomplete strings and you should be done.

Comment: Your way would work, but it's not most efficient if I want to replace the quotation marks with blanks(""). That's why I wanted to do in one go using `String.replaceAll(regexPattern, "");`

Comment: How is it *not* efficient? `String#replaceAll` will almost always be more expensive than a simple character replacement method call. Also, if you want the string sans the quotes, you can always return a view based on the `substring` call.

Comment: How would I do that? `if(string.charAt(0).equals("\"") and string.charAt(string.length() - 1).equals("\"")) newString = String.subString(1, string.length() - 2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
String regexp = "(?s)\".*\"";
String data = "\"This is some\n\ndata\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regexp).matcher(data);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match starts at " + m.start() + " and ends at " + m.end());
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kaj, this is fine, except that it matches the entire string. I only want to match the first and last quotation marks. I do like the `(?s)` idea. Thanks

Comment: .. that is because the first quotation mark is at the beginning, and the last one is at the end in my example. It will not match the whole string if they are at other locations.

Comment: That's true, but if you do a `string.replaceFirst("(?s)\".*\"", "");`, you'll get `""` back.

Comment: I guess, that's because my requirements are such that I need to replace the start and end quotation marks in one go.